# Build .DLL using MFC in a Static Library. C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc, static-libraries

I am upgrading some Windows applications (Legacy Code) from VC 6 to VS2010. The program I am currently upgrading uses a .dll and I would like to build it with MFC in a static library. 
When I set the "Use of MFC" option to "Use MFC in a Static Library" and the "Runtime Library" to /MT I get the following errors:

```
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxdllx.h(56): error    C2039: 'm_pFactoryInit' : is not a member of 'AFX_MODULE_STATE'

    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxdllx.h(55): error C2039: 'm_pClassInit' : is not a member of 'AFX_MODULE_STATE'
```

If I add _AFXDLL to the Preprocessor definitions, it solves the error but then I am asked to "Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds".

My Question: Is there a way to build my program, which is dependent on this .dll, using MFC in a static library?

Hope that makes some kind of sense, thanks in advance.

Comment: Was it a compilation error or intellisense? If the latter, this was [a known problem in VS2010](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/650507/intellisense-error-directive-please-use-the-md-switch-for-afxdll-builds).

Comment: @RogerRowland sorry it's a compilation error.
`fatal error C1189: #error :  Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds`

Comment: Did you ever happen to figure this out?

Comment: Does this error occur during debug mode or release mode ... MD switch is for 'Multithreaded Debug'